# Strange behavior using POST data in perl scripts

Tags: perl, post

Server is linux. I am having inexplicable problems when I send POST data to the script.

For example, I send the following POST data: `choice=update`

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";


  if ( $ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "GET" ) {
    $in = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
  } elsif ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST") {
    read(STDIN,$in,$ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
  }
  @in = split(/&/,$in);

  foreach $i (0 .. $#in) {
    # Convert plus's to spaces
    $in[$i] =~ s/\+/ /g;

    # Split into key and value.
    ($key, $val) = split(/=/,$in[$i],2); # splits on the first =.

    # Convert %XX from hex numbers to alphanumeric
    $key =~ s/%(..)/pack("c",hex($1))/ge;
    $val =~ s/%(..)/pack("c",hex($1))/ge;

    # Associate key and value
    $in{$key} .= "\0" if (defined($in{$key})); # \0 is the multiple separator
    $in{$key} .= $val;
  }

print $in{'choice'};
```

The first time I access the script, it prints `update`
The second time I access it, it prints `updateupdate`
The third time, it prints `updateupdateupdate`
...and so on.

What on earth could be causing it to keep appending the string to itself between requests? I am sending exactly the same POST data every time by simply refreshing with my browser. Cookies are not being used. There is nothing else in the file that is not commented out.

Edit: Also, when I `print <STDIN>` it says `choice=update` every time. The other `update`s don't appear to be added to `STDIN`

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using CGI.pm?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using `use strict;`?

Comment: To both questions, I understand that these are recommended things to do, however I didn't write the code. I'm just trying to make it work for someone and my perl knowledge is very limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the script is kept running between requests. As `%in` is a global variable it is never cleared, so that `$in{$key} .= $value` ends up making the string longer and longer. You can probably evade the problem by using lexical variables.

This means you'll need to find out how the script is being run by the web server.

You'll also want to look at using modules to do all this parsing work for you, and learn about ways to write perl code avoid the problem you've encountered.  I'd suggest taking a look at [Modern Perl](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2011/10/modern-perl-the-book-2011-2012-edition-draft.html) and working from there.

Comment: That was my guess too and that `updateupdate` is actually `update\0update` but the `\0` doesn't show up.

Comment: @Alex That the script is kept running between requests would definitely explain a lot of the strange inconsistencies I have been getting. I didn't know this was possible.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds / looks like it's related to the web server's configuration and not the script itself.

However, at the beginning of the code, try adding:

```
my %in;
```

This would scope the variable you're printing.

Also, at the end of the code I would add: `exit 0;`
(Although usually not necessary).